# Why a POST request on Node deletion in AEM

Tags: post, aem, sling, http-delete

In CQ's crx/de, each request that is made for getting the data or for creating a new nodes, rearranging nodes etc is being served by http://localhost:6502/crx/server/crx.default.
One thing i noticed is that for deleting the data, a POST request is made to the server instead on a DELETE request, and infact the payload defines that it's a Delete request, which does not seem very *RESTful*.

**POST REQUEST**
[image: POST Request]

**PAYLOAD says DELETE Node**
[image: payload]

is there any specific reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is because of the difference of REST vs RESTful.
IMHO RESTful means you try to adhere to REST principles however you don't force yourself to be fully compliant, actual reasons could be best answered by ADOBE.

There is [SlingPostServlet](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html) which could be used to modify the repository content and gets utilized for content modification.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a (good) rest implementation - says the fact that it is requesting 
`POST http://localhost:6502/crx/server/crx.default` and not something like `POST http://localhost:6502/content/mysite/jcr:content/node1/jcr:content`.

`DELETE`is supposed to be idempotent. so in scenarios where a server side logic processing is required and output cannot be the same for any number of request, a `POST` is preferred. use of `DELETE` and `PUT` tend to be minimal in complex systems for the same reason. (so far as I have seen).

Answer (score 1):

Apache Sling, on which AEM is based, does support DELETE requests directly to the resource that you want to delete, instead of going via `crx.default`. As far as I know this is enabled in AEM as well.